# Please can anyone explain How to read a Execution Plan for Poorly Performed Query in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, performance

Please can anyone explain How to read a Execution Plan for Poorly Performed Query in SQL Server?

Comment: venkat, since you obviously got some useful info from the people who answered your previous questions - it's common courtesy to comment on those and possibly accept an answer, so that people with the same problem won't have to ask the same question again. Please give back too, don't just take.

Comment: thanks i will keep this in my mind

Answer (score 1):

Check out some of the MANY resources on execution plans on the web, e.g.:

- [Execution plan basics](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/)
- [Graphical execution plans for simple queries](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/graphical-execution-plans-for-simple-sql-queries/)

Go to http://www.simple-talk.com and search for execution plans - there are many more articles and samples and even a free e-book on execution plans.

Marc

Comment: The simple talk article is very good, even if you have experience.

Answer (score 0):

- look at the diagram; it is a data-flow diagram showing the the basic operations (index scans, table scans, hashtable merges, et al) being performed
- find the section(s) with the highest percentage(s)
- think about what you can do to optimize that operation (hint: "add an index" is the most common solution)

post specific questions here if necessary